# xamarin forms: binding HorizontalTextAlignment XAML property to viewmodel property

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm learning xamarin forms and binding. I would like to bind the `HorizontalTextAlignment` xaml property to the viewmodel property MessagePosition:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding MessagePosition}"   />
```

where MessagePosition has a value of "Start" or "End". Unfortunately, it does not seem to work.

Explicitly setting:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"   />
```

or

```
<Label Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"   />
```

does work. 
The `Text` binding on the viewmodel property Message works as well.
Sorry if duplicate question...thanks for your time.

Comment: what is the type pf MessagePosition property?  I think it should be of type  TextAlignment  or something

Comment: What does your ViewModel look like? And why isn't it working? Nothing happens or you get an error?

Answer (score 4):

You should set the Alignment to a value of [TextAlignment](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment/).

XAML :

```
<Label Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding HPos}" />
```

ViewModel :

```
private TextAlignment _hPos;
public TextAlignment HPos 
{ 
   get { return _hPos; } 
   set 
   { 
      _hPos = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged(); 
   }
}
```